# Change width of Responsive HTML Newsletter Template from Charles Mudy

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, newsletter, responsiveness

EDIT: Template can be found at https://github.com/charlesmudy/responsive-html-email-template

I like the template, however I am having issues changing the width and having it respond properly, and I do not know why. In a comment at the top, it is mentioned to change widths, simply do a find and replace on the following sizes:

```
    wrapper   : '500',
    columns   : '210',
    x-columns : [
                    left : '90',
                    right: '350'
            ]
```

However, changing the wrapper to 750, columns to 335 (half of 750, then minus 80 for padding and such, just like 500/210), and x-columns to 142 and 448 respectively, things are not working as intended.

As I shrink the browser, the template is not snapping to one column until 480px, leaving the right column partially out of view from 481-750px. If I revert back to the original sizes, it works find. I am not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit your `@media` rule as well. It is located on `line 103` in the template.

You're adjusting the `width`s and `max-width`s of the template, but not accounting for the responsive design of the elements. Since you are essentially making all the elements *larger* you need to make your `breakpoint` larger as well. [You can read more about media queries here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

[Check out this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p4jgtgb7/1/).